# phase function in matlab fft

Tags: matlab, fft

I am wondering why the phase in a matlab fft behaves like this. This is likely more mathematical than matlab related.

I have a rect with a constant phase. The fourier transform shows a tilded phase for a centered rect. But with an offset of 2 the tild fanishes.

```
N = 16; w = 2;
data = zeros(1, N);    
data(N/2-w+0:N/2+w) = 1;

phase = ones(size(data))*1;
data = data.*exp(phase*sqrt(-1));

figure(3); clf;
plot(abs(data));

Ft = fft(fftshift(data));

Ftd = fftshift(Ft);
xaxis = 1:N;
figure(1);clf;hold on;
plot(xaxis,abs(Ftd), 'b-')
plot(xaxis,angle(Ftd), 'r-')
axis tight
hold off;
```

For an offset of 0 (centered) the ftt (shifted) looks like:

[image]

For an offset of 2

```
data(N/2-w+2:N/2+w) = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you applying `fftshift` to your time-domain data?

Comment: I would also suggest comparing plots of your time-domain functions...

Comment: Why should i Not apply the shift? If i Do Not the Phase is flipping between pi and -pi.

Comment: You can use `unwrap` on your phase plots to make that easier to interpret.

Comment: Okay. But why is it wrong math wise?

Comment: Did you do as I suggested?  (Comparing your time-domain plots)

Comment: What Do you want to know? One is centered the other not.

Comment: Here is a discussion about fftshift and when to apply it: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285244
The conclusion is that one must apply ifftshift before fft otherwise the phase flips as I already noted.